# How to call a function in a new terminal, inside a bash script?

Tags: bash, function, terminal

I've written a script in which I define a function and later I call that function in a new terminal. Something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

my_func(){
  echo "hello world"
  sleep 5
}

alacritty -e my_func
```

But I got an error :

> [ERROR] [alacritty_terminal] Failed to spawn command 'my_func': No such file or directory (os error 2)

I guess that new terminal doesn`t have access to the function I've defined inside the script.
How can I get around this?

Comment: Source the definition of the function from `.bashrc` or some other file that the terminal runs on startup.

Comment: Try exporting the function: `export -f my_func`. You may need to call the terminal like `alacritty -e 'sh -c my_func'`

Comment: @glennjackman I tried these, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`alacritty -e` will run a Linux command and you are giving it a function as an argument so it will not work.

The only way to make it work is splitting it into two scripts. I called them **echo.sh** and **function.sh**.

echo.sh

```
echo "Hello man"
sleep 5
```

function.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
alacritty -e ./echo.sh
```

Comment: Yeah, that works, thanks! But now I wonder if there's a way to do it within a single file.

Comment: I researched about it but there is none by using the alacrity, if you find a way to make it work in a single file, please share it over here, it will be useful for the community